# What are these two pipes coming out of the house?

Tags: hvac, water, pipe

I am trying to figure out the purpose of a couple of pipes that are currently coming out of the house.

First, a couple of notes:

- One-story house.
- HVAC system is in the attic.
- It is winter here. Running the heat. Using the water heater (which is in the garage). Not running the A/C.

The first pipe, shown here, I am pretty sure is the emergency drain line for the HVAC system. It is coming out from under an eave near the top of the house. Can someone verify that I am correct? It is not currently dripping.

[image: Emergency Drain Line???]

The second pipe is the one that I am not very sure about. It is actually dripping slowly, but steadily. I would say one drip every 3 seconds or so. It has been raining here, but I can't imagine this pipe having to do with draining rain water. Like I said, we do run the gas heater daily. And the hot water is, of course, used daily as well. The water heater is on the other side of the house in the garage. Any thoughts as to where the water from this pipe is coming from?

[image: Not sure what this pipe is for]

Comment: is it a high efficiency furnace?

Comment: Yes it is. (95% AFUE)

Comment: Does warm air come out of the upper pipe when the furnace is on?  If I had to take a wild guess, I would say the upper pipe is furnace exhaust, and the lower pipe is furnace drain line.

Comment: Can a furnace use this type of exhaust?

Comment: Where is the hot waterheater? Is it close to the bottom drain?

Comment: @Tester101, I would have to get a ladder and check when the heat is on, but for some reason, I thought that top pipe was connected to the furnace water pan in case it filled and then water would come out that top pipe as an overflow. My thinking was that it was put there so it is readily noticeable that there might be a problem -- not too often you see water dripping from a pipe at the top of the house.

Comment: @lqlarry, the pictures you see are at the back of the house. The hot water heater is towards the front of the house in the back of the garage.

Comment: @lqlarry High efficiency furnaces do indeed exhaust through PVC. Blew my mind the first time I heard it too.

Comment: @JoelMarcey If it gets cold enough to see your breath outside, you should be able to see the exhaust (if it is an exhaust pipe).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

High efficiency furnaces will make condensate. They run the air back through the hot exhaust to get more heat out. This also cools your exhaust enough to use PVC - that's what your upper line is.

In the process of cooling the exhaust, you might get some condensation. Typically that's collected in a little sump tank. When the sump reaches a certain level, a little bitty pump pumps it out - that's your lower line.

If it freezes where you are, you might want to insulate that lower line. If it freezes shut, your sump could overflow in the mean time. It's just a dribble of water, but still.  It's a leak of water in your attic.

Answer (score 1):

They both look to be condensation drip lines.     A/C'S will create condensation, especially in humid times.  The one coming out from to the ground could be from a waterheater, if it is close to the drain.

Comment: I could be showing my ignorance here, but, since it is winter, I am not running the A/C - only the heater, which would only turn on the furnace, right?

Comment: I live in a desert and the temperature has been in the 90's last week, I didn't go there with my brain.  But the upper pipe A/C is not dripping and the lower one is.  That's why I think it is the water heater

Comment: The overflow drain pipe from our hot water system runs about 5m through the wall (it was quickest exit along a wall), so "close to the drain" could mean "most convenient exit point at the time it was built" and not be all that close at all.

Comment: If your hot water system is like ours, there might be a lever that releases water through the overflow valve for testing. There's no harm in doing that (in fact, it was recommended to do occasionally to help keep it clear).